# Can Elmah handle an exception thrown before controller action execution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, exception, elmah.mvc

I'm using Elmah to log exceptions, and have been going nuts due to customers complaining about getting errors, but I don't see any 500s in Elmah's log.

The exceptions are occurring inside some attributes on model properties, when the model is being validated.  Obviously there's something wrong with my validation which I can fix, but I'd still really like Elmah to log these things if (when) they come up again.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
Balls.Web.Models.RespondViewModel.get_Declined() in c:\Users\Mark\Source\Workspaces\Balls\Balls\Balls.Web\Models\RespondViewModel.cs:19

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +192
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +136
System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture) +61
System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index) +21
Balls.Web.Models.Validation.ConditionallyRequiredAttribute.IsValid(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext) in c:\Users\Mark\Source\Workspaces\Balls\Balls\Balls.Web\Models\Validation\ConditionallyRequiredAttribute.cs:17
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext) +29
System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelValidator.Validate(Object container) +372
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.SetProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, Object value) +489
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) +830
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +180
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model) +106
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +2538
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +633
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +495
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +199
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +1680
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +94
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +559
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +82
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +73
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +105
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +588
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +47
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +65
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +139
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +484
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +98
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +73
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +106
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +446
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +88
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +50
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: can you show code where you do your validation?

Comment: That's weird. ELMAH normally logs errors during model binding. Are you using the ELMAH NuGet package or Elmah.MVC?

Comment: @ThomasArdal I have both.  I'm doing some more research now.  I just made a brand new MVC project where all I added was Elmah and Elmah.MVC, and looks like it's working.  Don't see any web.config differences

Comment: You could check how you use the HandleError attribute in both projects.